# Woocommerce show products starting with same name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my pages i sell mugs, t-Shirts, Pillows etc with a specific drawing printed.

For instance I have a drawing with Mr. Bean, he is printed on a bag, a mug and a poster: `https://art2u.dk/?s=Mr+Bean&post_type=product`

When I go to one of the Mr Bean products it would be nice if the related products where showing all products where name starts with Mr Bean.

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can easily manage this things with tags or brand(like a texonomy) to differentiate all the products. which should be display as related product as per the current product's brand

Comment: I would like to create a plugin, that does this automatcly, because i have so many products, that it would be a pain to do this manually